# What is the best way to correct parse log file?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, logging

I want to parse java log. I need to get only Error log with tracer.

For example:

```
2022-06-21 19:19:56,665 ERROR [scheduler-3] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at ...
    at ...
    ...
2022-06-21 19:19:56,666 DEBUG
```

I need take all until new log line with data. It is:

```
2022-06-21 19:19:56,665 ERROR [scheduler-3] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at ...
        at ...
        ...
```

What is the best way to make regular expression for this task with repeating symbols?
In my way there are something like that `.+\n\t`
If I not use repeat it seems ugly, like that `REG_EXP_2 = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\sERROR.+\n.+\n\t.+\n\t.+'`
So I need to find all log strings with model `.+\n\t` until I will find new data line.

I triet to use model with repeating symbols, but it parses only last finding string.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match ERROR amd all the following lines that do not start with a date:

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\sERROR\b.*(?:\n(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s).*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/06LALw/1)

Comment: Oh, its more simple than I thought. Thank you for your hint

Comment: Also thank you for regex demo tool. Very useful